# i am not able to run angular2 application with npm start however if i use npm run lite then the application is popping appropriately whats the error

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

**Code:**

```
{
        "name": "IPM_NG2",
        "version": "1.0.0",
        "author": "",
        "scripts": {
            "start": "concurrently \"npm run tsc:w\" \"npm run lite\" ",
            "tsc": "tsc",
            "tsc:w": "tsc -w",
            "lite": "lite-server"
        },
        "license": "ISC",
        "dependencies": {
            "@angular/common": "2.4.0",
            "@angular/compiler": "2.4.0",
            "@angular/core": "2.4.0",
            "@angular/forms": "2.4.0",
            "@angular/http": "2.4.0",
            "@angular/platform-browser": "2.4.0",
            "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "2.4.0",
            "@angular/router": "3.4.0",
            "@angular/upgrade": "2.2.0",
            "systemjs": "0.19.40",
            "core-js": "^2.4.1",
            "reflect-metadata": "^0.1.8",
            "rxjs": "5.0.1",
            "zone.js": "^0.7.4",
            "ag-grid-ng2": "7.0.0",
            "ag-grid" : "7.0.0",
            "ng2-bootstrap" : "1.2.1"
        },
        "devDependencies": {
            "concurrently": "^3.1.0",
            "typescript": "2.1.6",
            "opn": "^4.0.2",
            "lite-server": "^2.2.2",
            "@types/core-js": "^0.9.34",
            "@types/node": "^6.0.46"
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding for reference 
The problem was with the node and npm versions installed in my machine ,once updating them to latest stable release versions it resolved the problem .